# magic __get() on end($array) or $var

Tags: php, arrays, get

I want to access the last element of an array via php's magic __get method.

I am using php's end($array) to return.

If I do something like this:

```
class fun {
  protected $var = 'test';
  protected $arr = array(1, 2);

  public function __get($name) {
    return $this->$name;
  }

  public function get_array() {
    return end($this->arr);
  }
}

$obj = new fun();
var_dump($obj->var); //gives me: string(4) "test"
var_dump($obj->get_array()); //gives me: int(2);
```

everything is working fine. So far so good.

I don't want to use different "getters" for vars and arrays. I want the method to find out if a variable or array was called and then return the value.

I thought this would be easy done via the $name parameter, too:

```
class funfun {
  protected $var = 'more test';
  protected $arr = array(1, 2, 3);

  public function __get($name) {
    if(is_array($this->$name)) {
      $ret = end($this->$name);
    } else {
      $ret = $this->$name;
    }

    return $ret;
    }
}

$obj2 = new funfun();
var_dump($obj2->var); //gives me string(9);
```

but

```
var_Dump($obj2->arr); // gives me:
//array(3) {[0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3)}
```

If I dump it within the __get() method:

```
public function __get($name) {
  if(is_array($this->$name)) {
    var_dump(end($this->$name));
  }
```

it is giving me the "right" result: int(3).

Am I missing something?
Is it a semantic-Error? Is PHP's **return** not designed for this purpose?

Comment: I know it does not answer your question, but on my local php 5.4/win it seems to work as intended, I am getting 
int(3)
as a result.

In your example all I can think of is that the is_array check is failing for some unknown reason and that is why you are getting the 

//array(3) {[0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3)}

result.

Comment: thank you. i am running 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.17 on this machine. as soon as i am getting home i will test it on my own LATEST core.

no, the last var_Dump() part is within the if(is_array) statement. so the check should be fine

Comment: I think its exactly what is confusing you. Can you show me the code with the var_dump inside the class ? I think you are hitting the $array property and its not triggering the magic method, that is why you are getting such result.

Comment: On PHP 5.5.14 it's returning [the expected result](https://eval.in/321392): `int(3)`

Comment: yeah. i just posted an aswer..  looking at the class for 3 hours had crushed my mind somehow and i wasn't quite able to debug anymore. the original class extendet another class with the see below __construct() method.

Comment: It's always important to provide a working example of the issue if you can - an online IDE like eval.in will let you reproduce things for questions like this - anyhow, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem (at least here at home) seems to be a "get"-call within the __construct method. Forgot to check this in the original-code.

```
public function __construct() {
  $x = $this->arr;

  var_Dump($x);
 }
```

gives us:

```
//array(3) {[0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3)}
```

but:

```
$obj2 = new _funfun();

$x = $obj2->arr;
var_dump($x);
```

shows us the result: **int(3)**.

I will have a further look ath this under the *5.3.10-1ubuntu3.17* at work tomorrow. on my home machine *5.6.8* it is now working as intended.